# Change text color of a part of paragraph in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function to going through a paragraph element. And I have a dictionary. I need to check each word of paragraph with each key of dictionary and if they are matching, I need to color the original paragraph word in red color by clicking on a button.

JS function

```
function n()
{
var a = {German:["German1","German2"],plays:["plays1","plays2"],forward: 
["forward1","forward2"]};
var x = document.getElementById("p1").textContent.split(" ");

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<Object.keys(a).length; j++)
            {
                if (x[i]==Object.keys(a)[j])
                    {
                        x[i].style.color="red";
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<p id="p1">Marco Reus is a German professional footballer who plays as a 
forward for Borussia Dortmund and 
the Germany national team. He is renowned for his versatility, speed and 
technique, 
but also for proneness to injury.</p>

<button name="b1" onclick="n()">Next</button>
```

But after clicking on the button, Console says that Cannot set property 'color' of undefined at n. How I solve this?

Comment: First off, you can't color a single word using `style`, second, an array item is not a DOM element and don't have a `style` property, hence the error `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you can't color a single word using `style`, and an array item is not a DOM element and don't have a `style` property, hence the error `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`.

One possible solution would be to replace those words with themselves, wrapped in e.g. a `span`

*In below snippet I simplified your script, as you don't need to iterate all the words in the `p`, only the object keys and then simply replace the one's found.*

Stack snippet

```js
function n() {
  var a = {
    German: ["German1", "German2"],
    plays: ["plays1", "plays2"],
    forward: ["forward1", "forward2"]
  };
  var p = document.getElementById("p1"),
      keys = Object.keys(a);

  for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace( new RegExp("\\b"+keys[j]+"\\b","g"),"<span style='color:red'>" + keys[j] + "</span>")
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Marco Reus is a German professional footballer who plays as a forward for Borussia Dortmund and the Germany national team. He is renowned for his versatility, speed and technique, but also for proneness to injury.</p>

<button name="b1" onclick="n()">Next</button>
```