# How to highlight a word with a color?

Tags: javascript

I want to highlight the word in red in the "div", after pressing the space bar if it is not correctly entered from input and green, if correct. In my implementation I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined"

```js
    var arr = [];
    var i = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    txt = text.textContent || text.innerText;
    arr = txt.split(' ');
    console.log(arr);
    //alert(txt.substring(0,3));
};

function getChar(e) {
    if (event.which == 32) {
        if (e.value == arr[i]) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('form').reset();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium alias aperiam commodi
    consequatur corporis cum dolores eaque in labore molestias nam odio optio quas, quis voluptates!
    Architecto fuga impedit voluptatum.
</div>      
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="text_input" onkeydown="getChar(this);">
</form>
```

Comment: What's `i`? It's undeclaired and not clear what it must do.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that he wants to use it as an iterative index to his array - regardless, you can solve the error without knowing what `i` does

Comment: sry did not copy all the code :)

Comment: @IgorShvets You can't color a single word, you need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005351/change-text-color-of-a-part-of-paragraph-in-js/51005464#51005464

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that isn't going to work with your code.

- You shouldn't use html on-event handlers. Everyone will tell you "*yes you can*" - and I'm here to tell you that you sure can! but you **shouldn't**. Why? I guarantee you that you're going to run into more problems maintaining code and doing things like dealing with the event object. Alternatively use `addEventListener` - this provides you with the ability to manage your listeners through JavaScript code and furthermore add multiple events to the same elements. It also enables you to use fancy things like event delegation, which will save you in certain situations. It is a 100% improvement to do this and anyone who says otherwise is either new or crazy.
- You need to iterate over your array using `i`. This means that you can't declare it as 0 in the beginning of your code and simply increment it whenever you hit the space bar.
- You can't colorize text nodes. This means any freeform text that's not individually wrapped by a singular element is unavailable to style. We take care of this by creating a function that will wrap each word with a span. On the plus side you already have your text content being cast into an array, so we can pass that in, do our transformation, and spit it back out to be appended to the DOM. This is fairly simple. We use a `DocumentFragment`, which is what it sounds like. A chunk of page that you can append elements and text to behind the scenes, and then slap on your DOM all at once.
- You're storing data in the DOM. The initial text that you want to be analyzed should not be received by scraping text off the DOM. This should be manually input into your code and then rendered to the DOM from there. In the below example it isn't setup in an object or anything fancy, but in the future you should look at storing data within an object - why? So that if things ever need to change with that data it is 1000x easier to manipulate and change.
- I'm assuming that you cut and pasted the event for the keyboard check. `e.which` is deprecated. `e.key` is the new standard. Instead of checking for codes we can typically check for specific key characters.

  - When you enter in text and a spacebar is pressed it searches for text that is relative to the text you entered.
  - it adds the `selected` class to this text. There is no code here to remove the class and I'm not planning on providing it since this was a very large question.

The scope of what you're asking is much larger than I think you anticipated, and much larger than I anticipated, as a result I'm providing you with enough code to get you started with a working highlighter, but the changing of other spans to a different color is entirely up to you as I feel I've demonstrated plenty in this example. If you don't understand it, keep working at it, you'll get it.

```js
var arr = [];
window.onload = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  arr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium alias aperiam commodi consequatur corporis cum dolores eaque in labore molestias nam odio optio quas, quis voluptates! Architecto fuga impedit voluptatum.".split(' ');
  text.appendChild(wrapWithSpans(arr));
  var textbox = document.getElementById("text_input");
  textbox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    getChar(e)
  });
};

function wrapWithSpans(arr) {
  let df = document.createDocumentFragment();
  arr.forEach(node => {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = node + " ";
    df.appendChild(span);
  });
  return df;
}

function getChar(e) {
  let text = document.querySelector("#text"),
    spans = Array.from(text.querySelectorAll("span"));


  if (e.key == " ") {
    for (let i in arr) {
      if (e.currentTarget.value == arr[i]) {

        spans.find(function(node) {
          return node.textContent.slice(0, -1) == arr[i];
        }).classList.add("selected");
        document.getElementById('form').reset();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">

</div>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="text_input">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error would suggest, you haven't actually defined i anywhere before you use it - make sure you define it before using it as an index, such as by just writing `i=0` before your loop.

Comment: OP did, as you can see when we got all the code, hence this answer is now of no value. Always wait until these small things is cleared out before posting an answer.